# With PHP, storing image HTML into variables after submitting

Tags: php, variables

Apologies if this doesn't look right, or doesn't make sense, but any way to do the following...

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
  <img id="image1" src="URL" name="image1" width="138" height="79" border="0" />
  <input name="save" type="hidden" id="save" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update" /> 
  </form>
```

Whenever someone submits the form, the following would get stored into a variable...

```
  <img id="image1" src="URL" name="image1" width="138" height="79" border="0" />
```

Something like...

```
  $image1 = <img id="image1" src="URL" name="image1" width="138" height="79" border="0" />
```

Comment: is it just the url of the image you want to capture?

Comment: Ideally, the whole thing "<img src.... />" Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time imaging a use case where this would be the right thing to do.  If you store the value, and ever display it again, it would be very dangerous for XSS reasons.  If you try to clean it up before storing it, then why not just generate it from some sort of parameter list (i.e. save the URL and any other important parameters like width or aspect ratio) and either generate the tag prior to saving, or just save the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding the HTML as a hidden form element:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="?">
  <img id="image1" src="URL" name="image1" width="138" height="79" border="0" />

  <input type="hidden" name="image1" value='<img id="image1" src="URL" name="image1" width="138" height="79" border="0" />' />

  <input name="save" type="hidden" id="save" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update" /> 
</form>
```

Then it would be available as `$_POST['image1']`